# EF Nullable Foreign Key Relationship

Tags: entity-framework

I need some help today related to EF relationship. I have two lookup tables `Country` and `Ethnicity`. I want to have `nullable` `foreign keys` for both in one my table named `Singles`, so I defined a relationship in my class like

[Single Relation](http://goo.gl/0Gm5VI)

that generate a table like this, which is good so far

[Single Relation Result](http://goo.gl/tGSSEo)

But I have other fields like `Citizenship` and `CountryOfBirth` which require a `foreign key` as well from `Country` table. So, I tried to do the same

[Multiple Relation with Same Class](http://goo.gl/sq8OBb)

But things getting weird inside sql when table created.

[Multiple Relation with Same Class Result](http://goo.gl/XSRAu7)

I can understand why it behaves odd but don't know how to make it work. Can you please suggest?

Thanks

Comment: Please change the images into a format that SO can accept. Otherwise I'd have to have all of those images up at once.

Comment: Check to see if anything in the following SO question ends up helping you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839665/two-one-to-many-relationships-in-the-same-table

Comment: The solution you suggested not work for me. Because my Country is a lookup table and I am not defining any virtual property in it, only the Singles class has multiple virtual properties of Country. When I put the Inverse attribute in both of them it throws an error "The InversePropertyAttribute on property 'CountryBirth' on type 'MMN.DAL.Models.Singles' is not valid. The property 'CountryBirth' is not a valid navigation property on the related type 'MMN.DAL.Models.Country'. Ensure that the property exists and is a valid reference or collection navigation property."

Comment: How are you defining your foreign keys? Are you using Data Annotations, or Fluent API?

Comment: OK, It works I did a mistake. Thank you very much. One quick question, currently I make it work with Data Annotation, how it could be done with Fluent API?

Comment: I don't know. I personally use Data Annotations all the time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to place your `ForeignKey` attributes on the navigational properties to point to the nullable ID field (instead of vice-versa), and then use the `InverseProperty` attribute to properly tell EF exactly what kind of relationship you are trying to accomplish.

This answer will be quite similar to that in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839665/two-one-to-many-relationships-in-the-same-table).