# How to handle many to many same table (User) in ASP.Net MVC 5 - Fluent API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I am learning ASP.Net MVC 5 and I am stuck with one basic DB Design. 
So, I have one User which can refer many person in job
Also, many person can apply to get themselves Referred. I have created two roles and all of that is taken care. Now, I have on class called **Referral** which will keep track of every instance of Referral that needs to be done.

Referral Model:

```
Public class Referral
{
     [Key]
        public int ReferralId { get; set; }
        public Company Company { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public string CandidateId { get; set; } // Application User ID of person asking for referral
        public string ReferrerId { get; set; } // Application user ID of person referring the candidate
}
```

ApplicationUser Model

```
  public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ICollection<Referral> Referrals { get; set; }
        // rest prop removed for brevity sake
    }
```

Now, suppose A(Referrer) refers B(Candidate). My Table row will look like below.

```
ReferralId     CompanyId     CandidateId   ReferrerId

1              1             B             A
```

So, far so good. But I want to establish FK relationship on Referral table. I am new to Fluent API but I tried like below.

```
    // one candidate can have many referrals
    dBModelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Referrals)
    .WithRequired(u => u.User)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.CandidateId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    //one referrar can have many referrals
    dBModelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Referrals)
    .WithRequired(u => u.User)
    .HasForeignKey(u => u.ReferrerId);
```

But EF respects only one relationship. Why both the foreign key relationhip is not getting set. If I comment out one then other works, and vice versa. But keeping them together as shown never works.

Expected Behaviour: I expected to have two FK relationship. Once I have that then I can work accordingly. Please guide me here. I am new to all this.

[image]

Comment: You need separate `Referrals` & `User` properties for each relationship.

Comment: Sir, can you kindly elaborate what you mean. Let me know if I need to explain my requirement clearly. Also, I hope you understood what I wanted to achieve. I thought that If I set the relationship as above, I will use referrerId and canddiateId acccordingly to fetch/set the records. Please help me.

Comment: Even with current design everything will work, as long as I set the ID correctly. But I wanted to have proper FK constraint. Am I making sense?

Comment: @SLaks: Sir, I added one DB Design Image. Can you kindly see it once.

Comment: I think I have many to many in same table (ApplicationUser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SLaks mentioned in the comments, in order to have **two** relationships, you need **two** havigation properties (one for each FK).

So in the *one* side replace `Referrals` property with something like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    // ...
    public ICollection<Referral> ReferrerOf { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Referral> CandidateOf { get; set; }
}
```

at *many* side replace the `User` property with:

```
public class Referral
{
    // ...
    public ApplicationUser Candidate { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Referrer { get; set; }
}
```

and correlate them with fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.CandidateOf) // <--
    .WithRequired(r => r.Candidate) // <--
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.CandidateId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
    .HasMany(u => u.ReferrerOf) // <--
    .WithRequired(r => r.Referrer) // <--
    .HasForeignKey(r => r.ReferrerId);
```

The names of the navigation properties don't really matter as soon as you correlate them correctly.

Comment: Worked like a charm. While doing experimentation. I did add different property on Referral class. But I never altered the ApplicationUser. I needed to add different property there also.